# Unable to solve for x for an equation with independent variable in the exponent

Tags: r, matlab, wolfram-mathematica, octave

I am trying to help a friend in finance research. I wish to solve, for x, the equation that looks like :

[image]

g,h,c,p,a,b are all constants.

I guess the first step would be to find it's derivative. This I did, using an online derivative calculator at http://www.derivative-calculator.net/. I got this :

[image]

Further, I am trying to solve for x, assuming this is equal to zero. None of the online tools for 'solve for x' are able to do it. I have tried, Wolfram Alpha's online tool for 'solve-for-x', QuickMath, CynMath etc. All of them, 'cannot be solved'. I am looking for a solution like : x = blah-blah-blah. I have also tried the online Mathlab/Octave tools at CompileOnline/TutorialPoint. What can I do to solve for x, (preferably not having to install MathLab etc). Is there anything about these equations that render them incapable to be solved by Wolfram Alpha or such online tools for 'solve for x' ?

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oops, I meant, the second one, f'x = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write a function in R to solve your equation for a given value of x:

```
solvex <- function(x) {
  g = 1
  h = 1
  c = 1
  p = 1
  b = 1
  a = 1
  g * (1 - exp(h*x + c)) + p * (1 - exp(b*x + a))
}
```

Then, to plot the solutions over some range, do something like:

```
x <- seq(-100,100,1)
yseq <- lapply(x, solvex)
plot(x, yseq, type = "l")
```

Comment: Thanks, for that tip, on forumalating the function.  How do I determine what is  'range' ? In that research scenario, x is likely to take values between 0 and 1, not including 0 and 1. Values can however, go upto, say, 9 decimals. Does that mean, my range would be, say, 0.000000001 to 0.999999999 ? Also, would the 'plot' give me an equation as a result  ?

Comment: You should set the range to cover and include values that interest you. If there are specific values, no need to plot; just include them in x and inspect the results. As for whether plot gives you an equation, no, it gives you a plot; the equation to solve for x is embedded in the function. But now I'm confused. What is the output you want?

Comment: I was looking for an expression that'll solve for x, from the equation f'x = 0, the second equation above. Was not looking for a plot. Thanks for your time and effort. I now realize that I should've been more clear. As suggested by @nrussell , I since posted it on CrossValidated,  and got an answer there (not without causing some confusion). 
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161387/unable-to-solve-for-x-for-an-equation-with-independent-variable-in-the-exponent?noredirect=1#comment307060_161387

Can I still mark this as accepted answer, given the unclear nature of the question ?

Answer (score 2):

Finding a solution using Mathematica:

[image]